# When I am going to make war giving error like this (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)

Tags: java, javac

When I am going  to make war giving error like this (use `-source 5` or higher to enable annotations);

see the image:

[image].

Comment: Hi Nazimoddin Shaikh, welcome to Stackoverflow. Try not to attach images when you could also attach the plain text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: This is not the point, please read the meta article carefully. Adding images to read plain text is not preferable; just insert the relevant text directly in the question (quoted)...

Answer (score 2):

Are you using **maven** to build your war file? If this is the case you should check your projects **.pom** file to ensure you have set your java version correctly, within your build plugin.

```
<configuration>
  <source>1.7</source> 
  <target>1.7</target>
</configuration>
```

Comment: For backwards compatibility it might be preferable to use `1.5`.